# Memory continuously increasing on swift application

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm coding a generic Swift application (not for iOS, it will later run on raspbian) and i noticed a constant increase of memory. I checked for memory leaks also with the inspector, and there are none.
To dig deeper, I created a blank application for macOS, and I just wrote those lines of code, which are only for testing:

```
var array = [Decimal]()

while(true) {
    array = [Decimal]()
    for i in 0..<10000
    {
        array.append(Decimal(string: i.description)!)
    }
    sleep(1)
}
```

As I know, at beginning of every cycle of the while loop the entire array that was filled in the previous cycle should be deleted from memory. But seems that this is not happening, with those lines of code the process memory rises indefinitely.

I also tried the same code on an iOS project putting it on the application function (the one that is called at the beginning in the app delegate) and I noticed that in this case, the memory remains constant and do not rises up.

Am I missing something on the non iOS project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Decimal(string:)` is creating autorelease objects. Use an [`autoreleasepool`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/2299644-autoreleasepool) to drain the pool periodically:

```
var array = [Decimal]()

while true {
    autoreleasepool {
        for i in 0..<10_000 {
            array.append(Decimal(string: i.description)!)
        }
        sleep(1)
        array = []
    }
}
```

Normally the autorelease pool is drained when you yield back to the runloop. But in this case, this `while` loop never yields back to the OS, and therefore the pool is not getting drained. The use of your own `autoreleasepool`, like above, solves that problem.

FWIW, Apple has been slowly excising the use of autorelease objects in the Foundation/Cocoa classes. (We used to experience this problem with far more Foundation objects/APIs than we do now.) Clearly `Decimal(string:)` still is creating autorelease objects behind the scenes. In most practical cases, this isn't a problem, but in your example, you will need to introduce your own `autoreleasepool` to mitigate this behavior in this `while` loop.

Comment: I just tried it, and it is working, thanks! The only thing I did not understood is how Can I make it yield back to the OS (to let it drain the pool), if (in this case) after the while loop the process will end? Can I make this automatic without putting autoreleasepools in every critical point (like in UIKit)?

Comment: An example where you wouldn't need the autorelease pool is if, rather than a `while` loop, you did an asynchronous (aka `async`) dispatch of each subsequent iteration as the last step in the prior iteration. (As an aside, if you find yourself doing a `while true { ... } `, that's sometimes code smell for a deeper problem, so perhaps we should see why you're doing that rather than relying on runloops or the like.) Or, you could solve the problem if you did something that didn't requite autorelease objects (e.g. `Decimal(i)` rather than `Decimal(string: i.description)`).

Comment: At the end I created a DispatchQueue and dispatched every iteration with the asyncAfter method. No leaks on macOS, but when I run the same exact code on the raspberry the problem comes back and the memory increases indefinitely. This is probably to the fact that there is no `autoreleasepool` in the build for raspberry (arm) or ubuntu (x86/x64)